# Difference between https://<ip> and <ip>:443

Tags: node.js, https

I'm currently trying to understand the difference between 2 similar curl commands.

I spun up an AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance, and installed node.js on the instance. I then created a new directory called test-server. From within this directory, I ran `npm init`, then `npm install express`. I then wrote a simple web listener called `test-server.js`, which looks like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log('Got a request!')
    res.send('Request received!\n')
})

app.listen(443, function(){
    console.log('Server started')
})
```

Finally, I started the server with the command `sudo node test-server.js`, and the server started successfully.

Using `aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress`, I allowed communication from my local IP address to the instance over port 443. I then attempted to test the connection using the following 2 curl commands: `curl <ip>:443` and `curl https://<ip>`. The first command gave the expected output of `Request received!`. However, I received this error from the second command: `curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to <ip>:443`.

Now, I'm FAR from a networking expert, but I would have expected both of these commands to function in the same way. Based on this result, I have 2 questions:

1. What is the difference between these 2 commands?
2. How can I change the configuration such that the second command works as well as the first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your application is serving regular HTTP on 443 port. In order to use https protocol you need to use encryption keys

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.crt', 'utf8');

var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log('Got a request!')
    res.send('Request received!\n')
})

var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpsServer.listen(443);
```

Command `curl <ip>:443` is opening http connection to port 443 on given`ip`,`curl https://<ip>` is opening https connection to given `ip`.

If you want your traffic to be encrypted, stick to `https://` version (and  expanded code for server).

Comment: Note that this will stop the first curl command from working. You can’t have them both working at once, because they’re trying to access the same port using different protocols.

Comment: Ah, this makes a lot of sense. My ultimate goal was to get the second command working. I'm going to quickly test this out, and mark this answer as correct once I get the updated code working. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

> 1. What is the difference between these 2 commands?

:443 is simply the port configuration, no different than :80. It just tells the server to serve content on that port. 443 is traditionally the port reserved for HTTPS connections, similar to how 80 is traditionally standard HTTP.

> 2. How can I change the configuration such that the second command works as well as the first?

You'll need to install a TLS cert. HTTPS indicates that a certificate is being used to secure the connection, and the absence of that certificate will cause the request to fail.

Comment: Tomasz had a working solution before this, but this is still a great, informative answer. Upvoting